# How to develop applications for Windows Mobile using C?

Tags: c, windows-mobile

Well, I need develop applications for Windows mobile 6.1/6.5 and I'm looking for how to do this using C language programming. I heard that it's possible, but so far not found anything about, just support for C++/CLI programming language on older versions of VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [eMbedded Visual C++ 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24809).

It is free, too.

Just an FYI, though: IMO: Visual Studio 2008 is MUCH faster at getting stuff done.

Comment: I think OP wants to only use C?

Comment: I only coded in C when I used it years ago. Just leave the C++ headers out.

Comment: Well,looks like single solution. Thanks.